# How to deal with one inductor coupled with two different inductors?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, inductor, homework

[image]

I'm fairly confused on how to deal with this type of a situation. I can easily solve circuits with one simple coupled inductor, but this case is obviously different. The task is to solve for the voltage U.

I tried the following:

In order to make the task simpler, I solved for the equivalent circuit with the method shown below:
[image]

The above case is simpler, since the winding on L2 is only related with the winding of L1. For my case for the L1 I did jwM12I2, L2 voltage source I did jwM12M23(I1+I2) and for L3 I did jwM23(I1+I2). I am very uncertain if my voltage source value for the L2 is correct, because I pretty much just thought that it just makes sense to multiply the mutual inductances together for a inductor that is paired with two separate inductors.

So the question obviously is, if my values for the equivalent circuit voltages sources are correct, especially the L2 one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use definition of "coupling circuits" K.

Here is an example of such use.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite following. I don't know how I would use that information for my problem above.

Comment: Just to show it can be done in simulation ... but "something" seems to be "wrong" ...